# .NET Culture change event?

Tags: .net, culture

I have a .NET custom control that displays information in a culture dependant way. To improve performance I cache some information inside the control rather than generate it every time. I need to know if the culture has changed so that I can regenerate this internal info as appropriate.

Is there some event I have hook into? Or do I have to just test the culture setting every time I paint to see if it has changed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can either handle the [`SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.userpreferencechanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event:

```
SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged += (sender, e) => 
{
    // Regional settings have changed
    if (e.Category == UserPreferenceCategory.Locale)
    {
        // .NET also caches culture settings, so clear them
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData();

        // do some other stuff
    }
};
```

Windows also broadcasts the [`WM_SETTINGSCHANGE` message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725497(v=vs.85).aspx) to all Forms. You could try detecting it by overriding WndProc, so it would look something like:

```
// inside a winforms Form
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    const int WM_SETTINGCHANGE = 0x001A;

    if (m.Msg == WM_SETTINGCHANGE)
    {
        // .NET also caches culture settings, so clear them
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData();

        // do some other stuff
    }

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Note that you probably also want to call [`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.clearcacheddata(v=vs.110).aspx) to invalidate the culture info for newly created threads, but keep in mind that `CurrentCulture` for existing threads won't be updated, as mentioned on MSDN:

> The `ClearCachedData` method does **not** refresh the information in the `Thread.CurrentCulture` property for existing threads. However, future threads will have new `CultureInfo` property values.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you could do this by having your code change the culture via a central property that *itself* does something like raise an event; but be very very careful: static events are a very easy way to keep an *insane* amount of objects stuck in memory (i.e. GC treats them as alive). If you go for this approach, you might want to look at things like `WeakReference`...